# Luxon toRelative alternative wording

Tags: javascript, luxon

When using [Luxon's `toRelative`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetorelative), is there a way to tell the function to output e.g. `3 months old` instead of `3 months ago`? Or is there another method in the library? Or do I need to manually build the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of "ago" in the English locale is not customizable. You can see that it is a static string suffix by tracing the call stack in the source code from the [`toRelative`](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/3.4.3/src/datetime.js#L1999) method to the [final return statement of the `formatRelativeTime` function](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/3.4.3/src/impl/english.js#L165):

```js
return isInPast ? `${fmtValue} ${fmtUnit} ago` : `in ${fmtValue} ${fmtUnit}`;
```

Because of this, you can use a conditional string replacement approach as shown in the function `toRelativeCustom` below to achieve your objective.

> Note that Luxon's API does not specify the format of the relative date strings for any locales, so breaking changes are possible in the future.

```html
<script type="module">

import { DateTime } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.4.3/build/es6/luxon.js";

function toRelativeCustom(dt) {
  const str = dt.toRelative();
  return str.endsWith(" ago") ? `${str.slice(0, -4)} old` : str;
}

const dt = DateTime.now().minus({ months: 3 });

console.log(dt.toRelative()); // "3 months ago"
console.log(toRelativeCustom(dt)); // "3 months old"

</script>
```